# "upgrade alongside"?

Tags: upgrade

I had Ubuntu 16 running and upgraded online to ubuntu18 - the screen said this was installing 18 "alongside" 16.
Now 18 works fine, but 16 is still on the disk. How can I access Ubuntu16 to look for some old data?

Comment: How did you upgrade?

Comment: Hold left shift after boot and you should get a menu allowing you to choose which to boot.